# Error with bnlearn argument: iamb(bn) or gs(bn)

Tags: r, bayesian-networks, bnlearn

I tried to create bayesian network with function iamb(x) and gs(x).
But it showed "Error in check.data(x) : variable MFYield must have at least two levels."

Here is my code,

`bn[sapply(bn, is.character)] <- lapply(bn[sapply(bn, is.character)], as.factor)`

```
attach(bn)
```

this is sample of my data "bn":

`str(bn)`

`Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 59 obs. of  42 variables:
 $ MFYield  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ MWtA     : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ MWtT     : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ MClb     : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ MPS      : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ MTwU     : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ MTwD     : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ MTwDAgent: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...`

```
bn.iamb = iamb(bn)
```

The error begun here, when I try to create network.
Error in check.data(x) : variable MFYield must have at least two levels.

I am not sure that because my data is tibble? 
A tibble: 59 x 42
When I checked, it said:

```
nlevels("bn$MFYield")
```

[1] 0

```
class(bn)
```

[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

```
is.factor(bn$MFYield)
```

[1] TRUE

So, I think my data is already a factor, but R cannot detect it is already have two level. And I do not understand, why?

How can I fix it?. I quite a new beginner for R please help me to get through this.

Thank you.

Comment: this is because your data is a tibble. Convert it to a dataframe.  (ie many packages are written to comply with standard base r structures, which imo seems a sensible default)